# How to add usbnet driver to the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux

I want to add usb network support to a real-time Linux distribution we're using at work. 
USB devices are recognized, but when connecting a usb network adapter no network interface is created.

From what I've [read](http://www.linux-usb.org/usbnet/) this requires recompiling the kernel build with usbnet support enabled. I don't mind doing this, but the problem is that I can't seem to find any instructions on how to do this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! I've compiled more than my fair share of kernels.

First, you have to make sure you have your kernel's source on your hard drive. Look for a package called "kernel-source" or something. On my Slackware box, this installs the complete unmodified kernel source to `/usr/src/linux-x.x.xx.x`. A lot of times, different distros will have patched kernels, or custom configurations. A lot of the time, you'll find these saved in the file `/boot/config`.

If you don't want to mess with your system folders, I'd suggest you copy the kernel source to a temporary location before attempting compilation:

```
$ cp -rp /usr/src/linux-2.6.33.4 /tmp/kernel-build
$ cd /tmp/kernel-build
```

Next, you will need to get into the kernel configuration menu:

```
$ make menuconfig
```

This will do some initial compiling of the configuration menuing system and bring you to the configuration menu:

```
 .config - Linux Kernel v2.6.33.4 Configuration
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  l---------------------- Linux Kernel Configuration -----------------------+
  |  Arrow keys navigate the menu.  <Enter> selects submenus --->.          |
  |  Highlighted letters are hotkeys.  Pressing <Y> includes, <N> excludes, |
  |  <M> modularizes features.  Press <Esc><Esc> to exit, <?> for Help, </> |
  |  for Search.  Legend: [*] built-in  [ ] excluded  <M> module  < >       |
  | +---------------------------------------------------------------------+ |
  | |        General setup  --->                                          | |
  | |    [*] Enable loadable module support  --->                         | |
  | |    -*- Enable the block layer  --->                                 | |
  | |        Processor type and features  --->                            | |
  | |        Power management and ACPI options  --->                      | |
  | |        Bus options (PCI etc.)  --->                                 | |
  | |        Executable file formats / Emulations  --->                   | |
  | |    -*- Networking support  --->                                     | |
  | |        Device Drivers  --->                                         | |
  | |        Firmware Drivers  --->                                       | |
  | |        File systems  --->                                           | |
  | |        Kernel hacking  --->                                         | |
  | |        Security options  --->                                       | |
  | |    -*- Cryptographic API  --->                                      | |
  | |    [*] Virtualization  --->                                         | |
  | |        Library routines  --->                                       | |
  | |    ---                                                              | |
  | |        Load an Alternate Configuration File                         | |
  | |        Save an Alternate Configuration File                         | |
  | +---------------------------------------------------------------------+ |
  +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  |                    <Select>    < Exit >    < Help >                     |
  +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In order to load your current kernel's configuration (so everything you have currently working will still work once you install the new kernel and boot from it), select `Load an Alternate Configuration File` and then type in "/boot/config".

Next, navigate the menus to the option you want to enable and press the space bar until it reads "*" (compiled into the kernel) or "M" (compiled as `modprobe`-able kernel module).

Once you have everything right, exit the configurator and type:

```
$ make bzImage
```

This will make a the kernel image. Install it by carefully reading the `lilo` or `grub` man pages.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I don't need it anymore because a colleague of mine already started rebuilding the kernel :)